# Do I need insert a pixel tracking on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, yui

I have the following code:

```
[..]
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'www.example.com/pixeltracking';
[.. more stuff..]
```

that works well in Chrome but in Firefox I've never saw finish the request.

When I add the image to the DOM, now Firefox finish the load but chrome stop the code execution without any error message.

```
[..]
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'www.example.com/pixeltracking';
document.body.appendChild(img);
[.. more stuff..]
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need to insert it in the DOM, no. You may have another problem there. Did you check if your server sees the request?

Comment: Have you tried adding .onload() to the image object? Maybe the object gets garbage collected before loading finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you forgot `http://` in the url. Right now you are trying to load `www.example.com/pixeltracking` *relative* to the current URL, i.e. something like `http://yourdomain.com/foobar/www.example.com/pixeltracking`.